# Razor Ajax.BeginForm() creating a table with update form on each row. First Row missing <form> subsequent rows OK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, ajax.beginform

I am creating a table of items in a basket, using the following in razor to create an update quantity form in each row, however the first row has all the contents of the using but not the form tag, all subsequent rows work ok (ie. have correct form tags):

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.SummaryList)
{
    <tr id="basket_row_@(item.ProductCode)">
        <td>
            <img height="25" class="" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdImage)" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDesc)">
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
        </td>

        <td>
            @if (item.ProductCode != "DL")
            {
                using (Ajax.BeginForm("asyncUpdateCheckoutBasket", "Online", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "SubTotal_" + item.ProductCode }, new { id = "updFrm_" + item.ProductCode }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
                            @Html.TextBox("newQty", item.Qty, new { id = "newQty_" + item.ProductCode, @class = "form-control", value = item.Qty })
                            <span class="input-group-btn ">
                                <button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" id="add_btn_@(item.ProductCode)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pCode" value="@item.ProductCode" />
                }
            }
        </td>

        <td id="SubTotal_@(item.ProductCode)">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubTotal)
        </td>

        <td>
            <a class="text-primary" title="DELETE: Delete item: @item.ProductCode" href="@(Url.Action("RemoveFromBasket", new { controller = "Online", area = "", pCode = item.ProductCode }))">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Example of output:

```
<tr id="basket_row_KF00880">

<td>
    <img height="25" title="Q-CONNECT WHITEBOARD MARKER ASTD PK10" alt="Q-CONNECT WHITEBOARD MARKER ASTD PK10" src="https://online.calidore.com/BtoC/Images/KF00880.jpg">
</td>

<td>
    KF00880
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
            <input name="newQty" class="form-control" id="newQty_KF00880" type="text" value="1">
            <span class="input-group-btn ">
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="add_btn_KF00880" type="submit" value="Update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="pCode" type="hidden" value="KF00880">
</td>
<td id="SubTotal_KF00880">
    £8.21
</td>
<td>
    <a title="DELETE: Delete item: KF00880" class="text-primary" href="/RemoveFromBasket?pCode=KF00880">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="basket_row_KF00255">

<td>
    <img height="25" title="Q-CONNECT DVD-R CAKEBOX PK25" alt="Q-CONNECT DVD-R CAKEBOX PK25" src="https://online.calidore.com/BtoC/Images/KF00255.jpg">
</td>

<td>
    KF00255
</td>
<td>
<form id="updFrm_KF00255" action="/asyncUpdateCheckoutBasket" method="post" data-ajax-update="#SubTotal_KF00255" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">                                                
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
            <input name="newQty" class="form-control" id="newQty_KF00255" type="text" value="1">
            <span class="input-group-btn ">
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="add_btn_KF00255" type="submit" value="Update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="pCode" type="hidden" value="KF00255">
</form>

</td>
<td id="SubTotal_KF00255">17.98</td>
<td>
    <a title="DELETE: Delete item: KF00255" class="text-primary" href="/RemoveFromBasket?pCode=KF00255">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is that because your first product has the `ProductCode` of `DL` ?

Comment: I thought that, I've tried it without that test and looked at the data and it does not have and DL codes in it. It would be a simple fix if it was:)

Comment: Can you show us an example of the output?

Comment: Notice first div.form-group is missing a surrounding form tag